# Чи є український відповідник до слова "педикюр"?

Tags: іменники, запозичені-слова

У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pedykjur) знаходжу лише семантику слова. Якщо загуглити, вибивають лише відповідники до слова [манікюр](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/manikiur).

То чи є відподники до слова ***педикюр***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Словник чужомовних слів Павла Штепи](//ia902801.us.archive.org/8/items/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt):

> **манікюр** — рукодогляд
>   **педикюр** — нігтедогляд

Цїкаво, що включає, оскільки словник аж-но 1977 року. Загалом можна так вживати, однак я би внїс зауваги.

---

Спробуймо розібрати слова: *pedicure*, *manicure*.

Видно, що подїляють ся на:

- [*ped-i-cure*](//etymonline.com/word/pedicure), де лятінське (але індоевропейського походження) *ped-* (*pes*) є *нога* (*стопа*), можна згадати инше слово з цим коренем: [*педаль*](//etymonline.com/word/pedal). Тобто можливо доречніше було б **ногодогляд**, котре легко створює ся за [правописним правилом](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#prasklad) складних слів.
- [*man-i-cure*](//etymonline.com/word/manicure), де все так само, але з *man-*, котре є *рука*, теж є приклад иншого слова — *манускрипт*, котре також прижило ся як [*рукопис*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81), тому щодо **рукодогляд** нїяких питань.

Щодо останьої частини [*cure*](//etymonline.com/word/cure) теж відсутні питання:

> *cure* (n.1)
>   c. 1300, "care, heed," from Latin *cura* "care, concern, trouble," with many figurative extensions over time such as "study; administration; office of a parish priest; a mistress," and also "means of healing, successful remedial treatment of a disease" (late 14c.), from Old Latin *coira-*, a noun of unknown origin. Meaning "medical care" is late 14c.

Тобто *догляд* тут цїлком заходить. Також легко утворювати [похідні слова](/a/3004/585): *нігте/руко/ного[доглядач](http://sum.in.ua/s/doghljadach)/[ка](http://sum.in.ua/s/doghljadachka)*.